# GRAILS, ANGULAR, GRADLE --- Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'. --- npm finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: angular, gradle, npm, grails

I am developing a project in IntelliJ and I am using Angular for the frontend and Grails for the backend. The project is being built with Gradle, and I am getting an error for the Gradle task `npmInstall`.

The error is:

```
Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\thomasplantin\Documents\Office\dev\projects-grails-5\lotBoxWashG5\.gradle\nodejs\node-v10.21.0-win-x64\npm.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Does anyone know what is the source of this error? I tried looking online but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Few general things I could suggest

Delete the node_modules existing folder and try npm install.

And also check whether suitable node.js is installed.
If requires install node.js as part of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by downgrading nodejs via nvm like explained [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#overview). However I had the luxury of my coworker telling me which version of nodejs he uses.